# Drupal Sending Emails with Empty Body since change of Server

Tags: emails

Since we changed servers last week from Hostgator to UKFast, Drupal sends out automated php emails with a blank body. The only way we can get Drupal to send emails with the required body is by being logged in as an administrator and manually sending the emails. Does anyone know what could be the problem? This has only happened since we changed server.

Comment: Have you checked the logs to see if there's any glaring errors popping up?